# Help understanding the rigorous proof of the Clausius inequality

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I understand the proof of the Clausius Inequality by dividing a cycle into many infinitesimal Carnot cycles, but I am having trouble understanding the rigorous proof of the Clausius Inequality, as seen [here](http://theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/~judith/stat_therm/node30.html).

First of all, is the proof made for the Carnot Cycle pumping heat from the reservoir to the piston? If so, shouldn't the equation be $\oint \frac{đq}{T}=0$, since the Carnot Cycle is reversible?

Also, the Clausius inequality seems to hold for *all* heat exchanged with *all* the surroundings, and this proof seems to only take into account that heat which is exchanged with the piston. What about the heat exchanged with the reservoir?

Anybody care to enlighten me?

Comment: Link not accessible.

Comment: It is not the "piston" that exchanges heat but the whole thermodynamical system including piston, cylinder, gas, etc., is to be understood to undergo the process. The variables in the Clausius equality/inequality is of the *ideal heat reservoir*, that is, both $\delta Q$ and $T$ are the reservoir's parameters (heat exchanged and temperature) and not of the system going through the cycle!